# Making a disk usage breakdown

Tags: bash, linux, shell, unix

I'm looking for a better way of doing this code I made. I work for tech support and one of the biggest questions I am asked is: "Hey, how did my disk get so full in my VPS?"

I am aiming for output like:

> ```
> home/ is taking up xGB
> home/user1 xgb
> home/user2 xgb
> ```

and so on. So far I have this, which does alright, but I am looking for a prettier way of getting this done.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls -d */ |  grep -v proc);
 do
printf "**** $i has the following breakdown ********\n"

du -h --max-depth=1 $i
done
```

Comment: Even after you narrow it down to a specific user, you would still need to investigate that home directory. Have you used [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)?

Comment: yeeeee ncdu is alright... but doesn't script in too well... It's fine for me, being on my end, but I am trying to break it down dummy style for a customer that literally doesn't want to do anything. lol 
so my goal is to get the breakdown to look pretty and send it to the customer in a pretty pink bow

Answer (score 5):

## Use 'shellcheck' to spot common problems

```
200236.sh:2:12: warning: Don't use ls | grep. Use a glob or a for loop with a condition to allow non-alphanumeric filenames. [SC2010]
200236.sh:2:18: note: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options. [SC2035]
200236.sh:4:8: note: Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf "..%s.." "$foo". [SC2059]
200236.sh:4:53: note: Backslash is literal in "\n". Prefer explicit escaping: "\\n". [SC1117]
200236.sh:6:21: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
```

## Don't parse the output of `ls`

The `ls` program works well for interactive use, but isn't designed to be parsed by scripts.  The main problem is that whitespace and other shell-significant characters are shown as-is, with no quoting.  You could try to work around this using `ls -b`, but it's more robust to avoid the problem altogether:

```
for i in */
do
  if [[ i =~ proc ]]; then continue; fi
  # ...
done
```

## The test for virtual filesystems is too broad

`grep proc` will pick up names such as `processor` - do you really want to exclude them?  If you want to avoid inspecting filesystems not backed by disks, there are more reliable means:

```
case $(stat --file-system --format '%T' "$i") in
  proc|tmpfs|sysfs) continue ;;
esac
```

## Always quote parameter expansions

```
du -h --max-depth=1 "$i"
#                   ^^^^
```

## Don't expand parameters into a format string

Use `echo` or `printf`, but don't confuse the two (`$i` may contain `%`):

```
echo "**** $i has the following breakdown ********"
```

```
printf '**** %s has the following breakdown ********\n' "$i"
```

## Constrain `du` to a single filesystem

I'm not sure whether or not you want `du` to cross mountpoints.  If not, then add `-x` / `--one-file-system` to its options.

---

## Modified code

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in */
do
    case $(stat --file-system --format '%T' "$i") in
        proc|tmpfs|sysfs) continue ;;
    esac

    echo "**** $i has the following breakdown ********"
    du -h --one-file-system --max-depth=1 "$i"
done
```

Comment: WOAH!!!!! Implementing testing and thank you so much! @toby This wasn't just an answer it was knowledge and I appreciate it. ALOT